# Android-Prevent dismissal of dropdown in AutoCompleteTextView after item selection

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Even though I'm setting the setOnItemClickListener on the AutoCompleteTextView and performing some custom operations in it, once that method is done, the list dismisses and prints out the object.toString in the editbox.

I want to prevent dismissal of the dropdown on item select and would also like it to not replace the edit box. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I also want to implement the same i used below code to implement it.

Create a custom class and extend AutoCompleteTextView.

Override dismissDropDown() method and remove the super call from it.
Will work for you.

```
public class CustomAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView {
    public NoSelectionAutoComplete(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NoSelectionAutoComplete(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NoSelectionAutoComplete(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void replaceText(CharSequence text) {

    }

    @Override
    public void dismissDropDown() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added an onClickListener to the entire custom row layout that I was using for the dropdown adapter. This way whenever the row is clicked, my row onClickListener is invoked and the default one for the dropdown is not.

Answer (score 1):

**First Question - Prevent dropdown dismissal:**

Solved below.

**Second Question - Prevent text replacement:** (For others interested)

You can extend AutoCompleteTextView and override

```
protected void replaceText(CharSequence text) {}
```

to do nothing.

As others mentioned, overriding performCompletion() won't help here.

Comment: replaceText makes dropdown performance too slow.

Answer (score 1):

well at least it seems like they are planning to add this in near future.

```
/**
 * Sets whether the drop-down should remain visible as long as there is there is
 * {@link #enoughToFilter()}.  This is useful if an unknown number of results are expected
 * to show up in the adapter sometime in the future.
 *
 * The drop-down will occupy the entire screen below {@link #getDropDownAnchor} regardless
 * of the size or content of the list.  {@link #getDropDownBackground()} will fill any space
 * that is not used by the list.
 *
 * @param dropDownAlwaysVisible Whether to keep the drop-down visible.
 *
 * @hide Pending API council approval
 */
public void setDropDownAlwaysVisible(boolean dropDownAlwaysVisible) {
    mPopup.setDropDownAlwaysVisible(dropDownAlwaysVisible);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edit,new answer:
this worked for me but it closes for a sec,and opens again.

```
            class task extends TimerTask {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        autoComplete.showDropDown();
                    }
                });
            }
       };
    autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

             new Timer().schedule(new task(),0, 10);
        }

    });
```

Comment: I already have a TextWatcher. I need this to work on min API level 10.

Comment: I tried extending AutoCompleteTextView and overriding performCompletion, but that method never gets called.

Comment: @user1018916  there is regular `setOnClickListener` (only works on textview click) and there is `setOnFocusChangeListener` .the only thing i found is the snippet from the answer i gave you from api 17. apparently textwatcher doesn't detect the change from the dropdown click which is a bummer

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `replaceText` without calling `super` works fine (prevents entering suggested text into `AutoCompleteTextView`), but overriding `dismissDropDown` causes not-dismissing dropdown not only when item clicked, but also when `onBackPressed`, touched outside dialog etc...

I've ended with NOT using `setOnItemClickListener` method from `AutoCompleteTextView` at all. I'm creating custom onClick  in my custom `ArrayAdapter` and set it for all `View`s returned by `getView` method

```
View.OnClickListener onClick=null;

public void setOnItemClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClick) {
    this.onClick=onClick;
    /*this.onClick=new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getTag()==null)
                return;
            Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "position: "+postion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });*/
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ... call super/inflate convertView and do your stuff here
    setCustomOnClick(convertView, position);
    return convertView;
}

private void setCustomOnClick(final View view, final int position){
    view.setTag(position); 
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(onClick==null)
                return;
            // inside called onClick method v.getTag() will return pressed position
            onClick.onClick(v);
        }
    });
}
```

in fact setting onClick for whole view will cover "original" always-dismissing and always-replacing-text onClick (not called at all then). Remember about adding custom graphic representation, when pressed (ripple/selector are shown when "original" onClick called only)

I've needed also always-visible functionality, because my autocomplete must always show first position (functional), even when there is no suggestions (if present then shown below on positions 1+)

```
public class AlwaysVisibleAutoCompleteTextView extends AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView {

    private boolean showAlways=true;

    public AlwaysVisibleAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AlwaysVisibleAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AlwaysVisibleAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setShowAlways(boolean showAlways) {
        this.showAlways = showAlways;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enoughToFilter() {
        return showAlways || super.enoughToFilter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        showDropDownIfFocused();
    }

    private void showDropDownIfFocused() {
        if (enoughToFilter() && isFocused() && getWindowVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            showDropDown();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        showDropDownIfFocused();
    }

}
```

when `AlwaysVisibleAutoCompleteTextView` is focused, but dropdown dismissed and user press `view` again, then dropdown is not showing, because focus state not changing (`onFocusChanged` not called), so

```
autoComplete.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
                autoComplete.showDropDown();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

If you aren't planning using `setOnTouchListener` for your `AutoCompleteTextView` for any other purpose, then `OnTouchListener` may be set inside `AlwaysVisibleAutoCompleteTextView` class (in every constructor)